# How to add a chat bot to a Docusaurus V2 website?

Tags: docusaurus

I have written Docusaurus V2 website.

Now, I want to add a chat bot [Customerly](https://www.customerly.io/) to all the pages or one page. For a normal static page, we just need to add the following code to the `.html` file. But for a Docusaurus V2 website, does anyone know how to set it up?

```
<script>
    window.customerlySettings = {
        app_id: "abc7122d8"
    };
    !function(){function e(){var e=t.createElement("script");
    e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,
    e.src="https://widget.customerly.io/widget/abc7122d8";
    var r=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}
    var r=window,t=document,n=function(){n.c(arguments)};
    r.customerly_queue=[],n.c=function(e){r.customerly_queue.push(e)},
    r.customerly=n,r.attachEvent?r.attachEvent("onload",e):r.addEventListener("load",e,!1)}();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a script that initializes some form of authentication when the website first loads. Have a look at [docusaurus-plugin-google-analytics](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/master/packages/docusaurus-plugin-google-analytics/src), this is an example of injecting the GA script into a website.

You could make a similar plugin for your chat bot, you just have to replace `analytics.js` contents with the custom chat bot code you have.